# Swift - taking still frames from live camera and feeding them into Vision framework

Tags: ios, swift, computer-vision

Note: I'm almost completely new to Swift, so apologies if this seems like an obvious answer

I'm trying to code an app that can detect people doing exercises (think jumping jacks) and use that to control a simple game. I have a camera feed set up and showing on the screen, but I can't figure out how to get from that to still images/frames that it could analyze. My second problem is that, even if I knew how to do that, I don't know how to feed those images into the Vision framework to analyze them. Here's my code:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labelchange()
        //If it says to put it in the viewDidLoad function put it under here
        self.addCameraInput()
        self.showCameraFeed()
        self.captureSession.startRunning()
       
    } //Do any additional setup after loading the view
    @IBOutlet var thingtext : UILabel!
    func labelchange() {

        if typeChosen == "ice" {
            thingtext.text = "You're doing " + exercise + " for an " + typeChosen + " attack!"
        }
        else {
            thingtext.text = "You're doing " + exercise + " for a " + typeChosen + " attack!"
        }
    }
    private let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    private func addCameraInput() {
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(
            deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera, .builtInDualCamera, .builtInTrueDepthCamera],
                mediaType: .video,
    

            position: .front).devices.first else {
               fatalError("No back camera device found, please make sure to run SimpleLaneDetection in an iOS device and not a simulator")
        }
        let cameraInput = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
        self.captureSession.addInput(cameraInput)
    }
    
    private lazy var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
    private func showCameraFeed() {
    self.previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.frame
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.frame

    }
    

}
```

If anyone can help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated.